# Google unit test expects call of the method from exposer

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am trying to call `EXPECT_CALL` of the protected method of the current call. I have created an exposer of this method. Then I have added a method from the exposer to the mock.

```
TEST_F(ExposureGainController_Test, SetScale_call_SetExposureGain)
{
    TEST_DESCRIPTION("Check logic behind SetScale and auto call of SetExposureGain. ");
    ExposureGainControllerExposer c(camMock, scaleFunctionMock,
        std::unique_ptr<IMicroscopeOpticsParameters_ImageBrightness_Model>(new ImageBrightness_Model_Mock(0.5)));
    EXPECT_CALL(*camMock, RunSetExposureGain()).Times(1);
    c.SetScale(5.0);
}
```

In Exposer

```
void RunSetExposureGain()
{ 
       SetExposureGain();
}
```

// SetScale Function looks like this :

```
void ExposureGainController::SetScale(double scale)
{
    if (m_scale != scale)
    {
        m_scale = scale;
        m_gainInDb = ScaleToGainInDb(m_scale);
        UpdateResidualScale();

        SetExposureGain();
    }   
}
```

I am trying to execute `EXPECT_CALL`, but I can`t run it correctly.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What you mean by "I can't runt it correctly"? add your `SetScale` method.

Comment: Ah I can run it but it didnt call

Comment: With the information provided, it looks like your expect call is wrong. You are calling SetScale method from your test and expecting that call to RunSetExposureGain. Which is not happening it seems.